# Abrir questão fechada, id 87148

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

Enviei uma sinalização para os moderadores pedindo para reabrir essa pergunta:

[Quais são os requisitos básicos para criar um template WordPress?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87148/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-requisitos-b%C3%A1sicos-para-criar-um-template-wordpress)

Lendo os comentários, parece que a versão original continha um trecho em que pedia links para compra de themes, eu acho.

Mas do jeito que está no momento, não vejo razão para fechar.

Acho que bastava remover o trecho "inválido".

E particularmente eu acho a pergunta interessante.

Comment: Bom, agora o meta-efeito deve reabrir o post, mas acho que sinalizar não é o mais adequado, acho que é o caso votar pra reabrir; chamar a atenção no meta ou chat também funciona :) Eu já tinha votado faz tempo e caducou, na época não me toquei de fazer uma edição pra melhorar a criatura.

Comment: não tenho permissão para votar para reabrir.

Comment: Perdão, não vi que não tinha 3k (falta pouco!)... e talvez até essa flag vá parar na Fila de Análise de Reabertura em vez de na bandeja dos moderadores (a confirmar)... tudo azul então

Comment: Tinha uma resposta nesta pergunta, mas acho que o autor apagou, ou por ter sido fechada sumiu, não sei... mas também gostaria de ver reaberta, a possível resposta do @brasofilo muito me interessou... ^^ +1

Comment: @gustavox, tinha uma resposta sim o.O . . . . O normal é que o autor apague, não tem delete automático e só quando é alguma bizarrice o pessoal vota pra deletar.

Comment: Então Daniel, mesmo sem a parte do links, isto: "Seria interessante saber também quais são os pontos fortes e fracos deste tema" e " suas principais vantagens/desvantagens em relação a outros" são coisas que justificam manter fechada como principalmente baseada em opiniões.

Comment: @brasofilo nesse caso acho que não foi apagada pelo autor, porque os comentários migraram da resposta pra pergunta (mas já apagaram esses comentários)...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como fui eu que inclui este trecho (e na hora até fiquei na dúvida mesmo...), retirei lá, dá uma olhada se agora ficou melhor...

Comment: @gustavox Entendo, mas o original é quase uma opinião também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/87148/1 - fora que o AP nem voltou pra dar um feedback - o unico comentário dele foi na resposta excluida (Opa, valew.. não posso curtir comentario ainda, mas me ajudou bastante já :}) - ele acha que respostas são "comentários". Mas tudo bem, focando na pergunta, ela pode até ser salva, mas ao meu ver ela está muito ruim ainda pra ser reaberta. Pois ao meu ver o AP não tem muito conhecimento - me parece aquelas pessoas que customizam layouts e vendem. Ele quer pular o basico...

Comment: ... no entanto posso lhe indicar isto: - https://www.wptotal.com/como-criar-um-template-wordpress-parte-1/ - https://www.wptotal.com/como-criar-um-wordpress-theme-parte-2/ - https://www.wptotal.com/como-criar-um-wordpress-theme-parte-3/ - https://www.wptotal.com/como-criar-um-wordpress-theme-parte-4/ - https://www.wptotal.com/como-criar-um-template-wordpress-comments/ - https://www.wptotal.com/como-criar-um-wordpress-theme-sidebar-functions-footer/ @gustavox

Comment: Ok @GuilhermeNascimento, valeu pelos links!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Só pra constar, acho que em tese você tem razão, este tipo de pergunta não encaixa muito bem no site, mas na prática temos muitas perguntas amplas que acabaram gerando ótimas respostas, e foram/são muito úteis pra comunidade. E acho que este seria o caso desta pergunta, que tentei salvar (talvez piorando um pouco na edição rsrs) mais por causa da resposta (da expectativa :) )... mas entendo seu ponto, olhando objetivamente é ampla mesmo.

Comment: Então, mas o caso vai alem da pergunta, pelo tipo do AP, sem querer ser preconceituoso, mas me parece aquele tipo que pensa que sabe "alguma coisa" e vende layouts customizados, nada contra, só que não sou a favor de ajudar este tipo de pessoa. Talvez você pude-se criar um pergunta melhor elaborada (tenho quase certeza que eu respondi uma pergunta, mas não sei se foi aqui no SOen). @gustavox

Comment: Então @GuilhermeNascimento, mas o AP **não importa** (dei uma editada nessa frase  antes de enviar, era algo mais incisivo rsrs), o importante é que virá uma resposta boa, provavelmente mais atualizada e bem fundamentada que a maioria dos tutoriais, com a qualidade SO... Eu to instalando aqui pelo tutorial que vc passou (nunca usei o Wordpress, mas fiquei interessado por ver que tem muito mais templates que o Bootstrap - que é o que estou usando)... Com certeza farei uma (ou mais) perguntas sobre isso. ;) Em tempo: ah, já vi aqui que não tem nada a ver com o Bootstrap...

Comment: OMG é um framework PHP?!!! Eu pensava que era só CSS & JS... Mas não responda! rsrsr Depois que estudar aqui o básico vou pensar numa edição melhor pra essa pergunta... Valeu!

Comment: @gustavox vou responder sim kk - Então não é um framework apenas (framework bem ruim por sinal, mas funciona :) ), ele é mais um CMS e possuí funções próprias para "melhor" trabalhar os layouts. Então tem muito tema wordpress que usa bootstrap, digamos que o legal (nem tanto) do wordpress é a capacidade de criar temas para páginas dinamicas e no Dashboard criar seu proprio esquema de "banco de dados" (você usa a estrutura e cria os fields e values pra banners e outras coisas)... Agora se tratando de perfomance, wordpress vai dar uma canseira rs.

Comment: hahaha @GuilhermeNascimento já me desanimou :-) brincadeira, to aqui brincando um pouco com ele, vamos ver... mas o diabo deve ser integrar ele no meu projeto já quase pronto (que tá tudo em procedural, e to vendo aqui que o WP é OO)... btw,  não pra esta pergunta (que é específica sobre criar templates) mas seu comentário certamente daria uma boa resposta sobre WP, pq tem dicas valiosas, coisa que dificilmente se encontra por aí (e *mutatis mutandis* acho que poderia acontecer o mesmo na pergunta de origem) ... Valeu +1

Comment: A questão é que eu não entendi porque é uma questão que pode ser baseada em opiniões. É uma questão técnica específica, pois para criar os themes precisa seguir as especificações da plataforma do WP. Uma resposta certa seria fazer uma resposta wiki, pegando dados do manual do wordpress.. acho que só isso já basta..

Comment: Fui eu que transformei a resposta em comentário pois ela... bem, ela não era uma resposta :) Eu também fiz uma limpa nos comentários que não eram mais pertinentes ao assunto. Sobre a sinalização, @brasofilo, por ser uma sinalização personalizada ela vem para a fila de análise dos mods e somente nós temos temos acesso, portanto realmente não é o mais indicado. Eu fiz o que pude para tentar reabri-la (fiquei cutucando o entendedor brasofilo até ele arrumar a pergunta, heuheue), mas o mais indicado realmente é sinalizar ou comentar para que todos vejam, e não apenas os mods.

Comment: @gustavox a resposta convertida em comentário foi mantida, está aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87148/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-requisitos-b%C3%A1sicos-para-criar-um-template-wordpress#comment178208_87148

Comment: Ah agora que vi que está como comentário... nice one imho @Math

Comment: Daniel foi fechada como baseada em opiniões desde antes de qualquer edição e o motivo foi está parte da pergunta "Alguem pode me indicar o que estudar antes para me aperfeiçoar?" -- Além disto, está claro que o AP não tem noção alguma da tecnologia e quer pular muitos passos, ele alega entender de html5, css, jquery e design responsivo, mas não fala de javascript e não entende a diferença do wordpress do bootstrap (Que comparação estranha...). Suponho que ele seja um destes caras que customiza e vende layouts prontos e provavelmente pegou um cliente que usa wordpress...

Comment: ...Eu acho que não vale a pena responder a pergunta dele, por mais de um motivo, no entanto Daniel, se você tiver a resposta eu recomendo que você crie a pergunta e você mesmo responda, ou então se você tiver uma duvida semelhante você pode criar uma pergunta semelhante e tenho certeza que haverá muitas respostas e pontos pra ti :) - posso até arriscar uma resposta. Mas vou ser sincero, responder aquela pergunta acho que não vai levar a lugar nenhum (é apenas a minha opinião).

Comment: ahh entendi!.. Como que faço para ver o original antes de uma edição? Acho que tem um recurso mas talvez eu ainda não tenha permissão. Mas do jeito como vc descreveu, aí sim, eu tb teria marcado para fechar..

Comment: @DanielOmine Procure no rodape da pergunta aonde está escrito algo como "editada ontem" e clique nela, role até o final da página, o ultimo item é o original. Se quiser o link direto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/87148/1

Comment: valeu!! vai me ajudar em outros topicos.

Answer (score 1):

Nossa... que isso pessoal, eu entendo sim, não sou "O Webmaster fodelão" ainda kkkk, mas tambem não sou leigo no assunto. Muito menos "vendo layouts prontos" huahua

Tambem uso bootstrap sim, e sei a diferença entre um Framework e um CMS.
Porém, há alguns meses comecei a usar o wordpress, joomla...
Mas como disseram acima, realmente, nestes casos apenas fazendo a customização de temas premium. Pois me ajuda bastante em questão de produtividade na hora de alimentar o site. Além do que, alguns clientes preferem pagar dobrado contanto que eu  os ensine a alimentar o "blog" ou "noticias" do site sozinho. Claro, só ofereço quando me compensa.

Mas tambem monto layouts sem CMS.

Só o que eu pedi foi um material para me aprofundar, quero saber adaptar um layout meu, criado do zero para o wordpress.

Os links do Guilherme me ajudaram bastante, era somente isso que eu precisava.

Muito obrigado a todos os envolvidos! E me desculpem o transtorno. 
Sou novo na stackoverflow. 
To começando a entender que não é o tipo de forum que eu pensava, hehe.

Inclusive se puderem me indicar um forum à parte para questões deste tipo, agradeço de coração. Abraço!

Comment: Legal que veio responder aqui no meta, mostra interesse. Pode dar um lida em: [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/91) quando tiver  tempo :) +1

Comment: Talvez você goste de conhecer o [chat], ou não.. Mas pode tentar :)

Comment: Então Vinny, legal que veio participar, isto é muito bom pra comunidade, demonstra que é uma pessoa participativa. O problema realmente foi como a questão foi formulada, entende? Não é nada pessoal, não afirmei que vendia layouts, apenas fiz uma suposição (é que vejo muitos customizadores por ae, inclusive conheço um) e também não estou desmerecendo que faz este tipo de coisa. A questão realmente é que parece que você está pulando os princípios basicos de quem vai começar a usar tecnologias web. No caso o wordpress é em php e saber php é o basico pra entender o wordpress (ao meu ver)...

Comment: Mas acredito que pelo seu modo participativo aqui e com uma boa edição talvez a questão possa ser reaberta, não acredito que precise ir pra um fórum. Note que pra reabrir não depende apenas de uma pessoa pra reabrir. Que bom que os links lhe ajudaram. Uma abraço!

Comment: não há problema algum em vender "layout pronto".. Há discriminação sim, mas isso é bobagem. Quem recrimina os que vendem layout ou sistema "pronto", é muito amador do ponto de vista comercial. O que mais vale é o negócio em si, o business $$. Se formos pensar em repudiar a revenda, então devemos repudiar toda a cadeia de atacado e varejo de qualquer coisa. Um mercado vende banana sem saber como produzí-la. Mas vc pode plantar banana no quintal de casa, por que então vc compra do mercado que está apenas revendendo a banana pronta? Os developers em geral tem que aprender a enxergar o business.

Comment: um profissional que se garante não precisa se sentir incomodado com os amadores e iniciantes que se jogam de qualquer jeito no mercado pois normalmente os iniciantes pegam aqueles clientes "pé rapados", "mesquinhos", que não pagam nem 20 reais num sistema que vai lhe render 10 mil ao mês, de tão mesquinho e medíocre que é.. rsrsr.. Um bom profissional, que "se acha" acima dos amadores, deveria estar focado nos clientes mais sólidos e sérios. Para esses clientes sérios, vc pode oferecer um sistema por 100 mil reais que vende tranquilo e sem choro. O cliente ainda acha barato e fica com dó. rsrs

Comment: Tá vendo, tem informações que você coloca aqui no Meta que *tinha que estar* lá no site principal. É só editar a pregunta (não fazer comentários, mas sim **editar** a pergunta acrecentando detalhes técnicos). Não é transtorno nenhum, é só que a comunidade zela pela qualidade do conteúdo. Note que perguntar por dicas ou links não é bemvindo no site principal.

Comment: @DanielOmine é como eu disse, eu não estou criticando a venda e nem este tipo de trabalho e este não é o assunto, o problema é que do meu ponto de vista o AP estava querendo pular passos basicos, indo do suposto conhecimento de front-end para o wordpress sem entender. Pode ser que eu esteja enganado sobre ele querer pular passos, mas a minha opinião é que qualquer resposta ali iria gerar uma LONGA discussão. :) Felizmente o AP se mostrou sensato e parece ter bastante interesse em aprender.

Comment: Vinny, posso dizer pela experiência própria de quem ainda tá aprendendo o básico: existem muitos fóruns por aí, mas as respostas estão aqui. ;)

Comment: Valew galera, agora entendi como funciona.. hehe abç!