# Minha pergunta foi marcada como duplicada fechada de forma arbitrária utilizando questões fora do escopo da pergunta

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas, perguntas-fechadas

Fiz uma pergunta relativa ao SQL

[Como o SQL injection desse XKCD funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376580/como-o-sql-injection-desse-xkcd-funciona)

e inicialmente minha pergunta foi marcada como duplicada.

Gostaria de salientar que há uma questão como essa, com milhares de votos [no stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365). Ao que tudo indica o mérito da questão em si é importante e só estou utilizando esse fato para dizer que esse conhecimento foi considerado útil e importante por milhares de usuários.

O meu questionamento é:

1) minha questão foi marcada como duplicada fornecendo outras duas questões que estão ligeiramente fora do escopo da minha e são suficientemente diferentes;

2) a questão foi fechada minutos depois de ser feita sem a devida apreciação de muitos usuários, isto é, a opinião de um único moderador valeu mais que a opinião de muitos outros;

3) minha questão tem méritos em si e um escopo muito bem definido, tal que impedir a questão de ser respondida e fornecer como alternativa questões que estão ligeiramente fora do escopo, no meu entender, é simplesmente adicionar ruído a informação que se quer registrar aqui no SOpt.

Comment: EDIT: como houve remoçao da acusação, reverti meu negativo (que foi dado só aqui, lá não votei nem up nem down).

Comment: Você escreveu isso no seu post para eleição: "Em vez de tentar combater fechamentos e negativos, melhor explicar para os novos usuários que são ocorrências naturais, mostrando como resolver os problemas das postagens." Tá aí um motivo para nunca votar em você novamente. Você deveria seguir o que você afirmou como sua plataforma para eleição em 2018...

Comment: Estou votando para fechar essa pergunta como fora do escopo porque ela parte de muita especulação e acusações sem argumentos e dificilmente servirá para uma discussão saudável aqui no Meta. Uma coisa é questionar o fechamento, outra é fazer acusações avulsas.

Comment: Parece o STF 2019. Qual o problema em se discutir o mérito da pergunta?

Comment: A grande questão é: forneço com duplicata alternativas que claramente fogem do escopo da pergunta. O fechamento é plausível nestes casos? Minha opinião é que não. No mínimo o ideal seria deixar para pelo menos alguns outros usuários avaliarem. No meu entender marcar a questão como duplicata nestes casos é arbitrário sim.

Comment: Nenhum, mas foi exatamente a única coisa que você não fez na sua pergunta. Ela é composta de 4 partes: 1) Uma breve introdução dizendo que criou a pergunta; 2) Link; 3) Uma acusação de que o Bacco teria te negativado; 4) Uma afronta ao Bacco dizendo que ele seria mais inteligente que milhares de usuários do SOen. Nenhum destes tópicos discute o mérito da pergunta.

Comment: Eu não fiz uma afronta ao @Bacco dizendo que "dizendo que ele seria mais inteligente que milhares de usuários do SOen.". O que eu indiquei é que há uma pergunta similar com milhares de likes lá e o fato de que uma única pessoa fechou a questão aqui.

Comment: Eu recomendaria excluir essa pergunta e abrir uma nova esclarecendo mais diretamente o seu ponto. Se está querendo discutir o fechamento da questão, o que o fato de ser negativado interfere? E mais, no que muda se foi o Bacco ou não o autor do negativo? Eu passei isso para você na pergunta e passarei aqui de novo, talvez não tenha visto, [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/5878) - dizer que sua pergunta deveria permanecer aberta porque está aberta lá não é um argumento válido.

Comment: Meu argumento não foi que a minha pergunta deveria estar aberta aqui porque está aberta lá. Meu argumento é: 1) a pergunta foi fechada por um único usuário minutos depois de ser feita e com poucas visualizações; 2) inicialmente o usuário forneceu duas perguntas como duplicatas que não são exatamente a mesma coisa; 3) acredito que a pergunta tem um mérito em si, independentemente das outras duas.

Comment: Conforme comentei lá, a [pergunta original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365) do SOen é de 2008 e até mesmo os critérios do próprio Stack Overflow mudaram de lá pra cá, tanto que hoje em dia se vc só perguntar "what's sql injection?", provavelmente será fechada como duplicada lá também... Sobre trazer conteúdo em inglês para cá, vale ler a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english).

Comment: E sobre duplicadas, só porque as outras perguntas focam em alguma linguagem, não quer dizer que as respostas não sirvam (em especial [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100731/112052) - e a que o @AndersonCarlosWoss sugeriu tb - cujo exemplo explica como acontece - independente de estar em C#, isso ocorre do mesmo jeito em qualquer linguagem, pois é a concatenação de strings que gera uma query potencialmente perigosa e que configura o ataque de injeção de SQL). O que define uma duplicada não é "as perguntas são 100% iguais" e sim "as respostas de uma também servem para a outra" :-)

Comment: @FlavioBarros Nada do que você está comentando está presente nesta sua pergunta. Eu manterei o meu voto de fechamento e a minha sugestão que se quer, de fato, discutir o mérito de fechamento, que faça da forma correta em uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Mas sem analisar o mérito da pergunta?

Comment: Leituras interessantes: [A minha pergunta foi fechada e agora?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7470/5878), [Pergunta fechada, porém válida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6228/5878), [Abrir questão fechada, id 87148](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4376/5878), [Esta pergunta merece mesmo ser fechada como fora do escopo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6907/5878), [Pergunta negativada e fechada mas que parece ok](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4620/5878), [Porque esta pergunta deve ser fechada?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2412/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss pronto, qual o problema agora com a minha pergunta? Vamos analisar o mérito?

Comment: Caro Flávio, não vim falar do fechamento e nem da moderação, eu queria mesmo saber se conseguiu entender como o ocorre o SQLInjection, porque suspeito que o problema todo ali seja no seu caso procurar o entendimento disto. Vou tentar resumir, o DROP lá é irrelevante, poderia ser qualquer comando, para resumir o `nome');` passado via INPUT para a query é quem começou a causa da injeção, o `--` só fez ignorar as instruções posteriores e o `DROP` (que poderia ser qualquer comando) veio via INPUT, ou seja o apostrofo `'` após o nome Robert que "começou/causou" a injeção[...]

Comment: [...] Para tratar isso seria necessário escapar o tal apostrofo, mas quem desenvolveu o sistema não o fez. Ou seja se o INPUT tivesse sido tratado antes de passar para query teria algo como: `INSERT INTO pessoas (nome) VALUES ('Robert\'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --')` ao invés de `INSERT INTO pessoas (nome) VALUES ('Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --');`. Veja que o no segundo caso o **apostrofo** encerraria a instrução e no primeiro caso (que foi escapado) o `');` e todo resto fazem parte do valor inserido.

Comment: Prezado @GuilhermeNascimento eu gostaria de discutir aqui o fechamento da questão. Dada a arbitrariedade do fechamento e o fato de o meta não ser o lugar apropriado para responder essa questão, colocar a resposta aqui é irrelevante. O fato de você estar pré-disposto a responder só reforça o fato de que a questão deveria estar aberta. Você bem poderia responder e comentar lá onde outros usuários interessados no assunto poderiam replicar.

Comment: @FlavioBarros entendo seu ponto de vista, mas para eu me posicionar sobre isto e considerar ou não abertura vs fechamento eu tenho que entender aonde exatamente esta o seu entendimento do assunto técnico discutido na pergunta, não concordo que seja só porque comentei aqui motivo suficiente para reabrir, preciso analisar todos pontos antes de votar para reabertura ;), espero que entenda que ninguém fecha nada por mal, pq se fosse o caso nem existiria voto de fechamento, estou comentando aqui justamente porque quero ver como posso lhe ajudar na pergunta e no problema técnico.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o que quero dizer é que o objetivo do stackoverflow é armazenar o conhecimento não tácito por meio da estrutura de perguntas e respostas, um conhecimento que poderia ser utilizado por outras pessoas. Aqui esse objetivo não seria cumprido.

Comment: Também, para analisar o mérito da questão não é necessário saber o meu entendimento do assunto já que isso é algo que poderia ser esclarecido nos comentários e em uma resposta no próprio stackoverflow. Por fim, agora que estou ciente da resposta no SOen a resposta lá já foi suficiente para mim, ainda que mesmo assim outros leitores do SOpt possam não ter acesso a resposta.

Comment: A pergunta do SOen foi feita lá no início do site, há mais de 10 anos, e acabou se tornando a pergunta canônica sobre o tema por lá, com várias outras duplicatas apontando para ela. Essas duplicatas não tratam necessariamente da tirinha, mas de SQL injection. Aqui aconteceu diferente, as primeiras perguntas sobre o tema, que estão a caminho da "canonização", não eram diretamente sobre a tirinha. Com isso em mente, sobre o mérito da sua pergunta, o que você considera que ela acrescenta?

Comment: Tudo bem Flávio, não discordo sobre armazenar conhecimento, mas realmente preciso saber se conseguiu entender que o causador do injection ali foi o apostrofo não tratado, porque assim vou tentar argumentar se o problema realmente foi respondido nas outras perguntas ou não, é que me deu a entender que vc pensou que o DROP era o problema, mas a questão é um pouco mais complexa. Realmente só estou querendo lhe ajudar e orientar. Por favor veja como boa as minhas intenções aqui ;)

Comment: Eu ia participar do debate mas dada a quantidade enorme de falácias expostas prefiro nem gastar meu tempo ,estou em férias! Me desculpe, mas não é assim que consiguirá reverter a situação de qualquer estou só vendo se tem amsi algum link na minha resposta que foi linkada, vê lá se ainda não está claro na resposta que já não era sobre C#. Eu tinha propositalmente dado uma resposta mais canônica como gosto de fazer para que outras pessoas não precisem perguntar de novo. Não faz a menor diferença se é C#. A sua será um ótimo ponto de entrada, só que não precisa de uma resposta nova.

Comment: E não tome como algo contra a sua pergunta ou pessoa, estamos apenas mantendo a organização do site. Não tem necessidade ter duas respostas iguais em lugares diferentes.

Comment: Prezado @GuilhermeNascimento eu entendo suas intenções perfeitamente. Só não entendo aqui ser o espaço para essa discussão. A resposta no SOen é bastante clara. Há várias respostas lá sobre isso. Mas ainda assim, mesmo que fosse o caso de eu ainda não entender o que foi perguntado, mesmo que fosse satisfeita a minha dúvida, ainda assim teríamos o problema de esse conhecimento não ser compartilhado, o que no meu entender vai contra o objetivo do SO.

Comment: @Maniero quando minha pergunta foi fechada eu peguei a imagem e procurei no google imagens e achei a pergunta. Do meu ponto de vista poderia ter lido e estar OK, mas achei o fechamento arbitrário e por isso estou discutindo esse fechamento aqui. Ficou claro?

Comment: Agora entendi melhor o que está acontecendo vendo a pergunta do SOen. Copiar perguntas de forma idêntica ao SOen nunca foi a melhor coisa a se fazer. O contexto é totalmente diferente, e meio que já explicaram, foram caminhos diferentes que cada comunidade tomou, aquela nasceu primeiro, ela só não é duplicata por causa disto, a sua é porque tantas outras surgiram antes. Uma das coisas que se fala em trazer perguntas de lá pra cá é justamente olhar o contexto primeiro, ver se ela realmente é necessária, nesta forma, hoje, ela não é, já existe resposta para isto.

Comment: Prezado @Maniero eu fui advertido aqui de que eu estava acusando de me dar downvote. Eu concordei com fato e até apaguei a minha pergunta e reformulei. Eu tenho a impressão que estou sendo acusado de copiar uma pergunta do SOen.

Comment: Flavio, então sugiro que releia o último comentário do @Maniero, não é isso que ele está dizendo.

Comment: Pronto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101 acho que encerro aqui e volto pras minhas férias do site porque fica cada vez mais claro que vamos enxugar gelo.

Comment: Pra quebrar um pouco o "climão", uma coisa ficou clara: essa discussão toda serviu para mostrar que nenhuma pergunta ou resposta do site até agora incluía a tirinha do bobby tables. Isso estou de acordo que seja inadmissível :)

Comment: @bfavaretto todos concordamos, agora tem.

Comment: Pois é, agora depois que eu faço a pergunta, tomo 4 downvotes o @Maniero edita a resposta dele incluindo isso e a minha pergunta continua fechada. Isso é plágio! (isso é uma ironia...)

Comment: Prezado @AndersonCarlosWoss você leu a parte da ironia? A discussão aqui não precisa ser infinita ;-)

Comment: Ok Flávio, eu sei que vocês debateram e talvez você até tenha chegado a concordância com os demais, mas preciso fazer uma pergunta sincera, das 3 perguntas linkadas na sua (nas 3 perguntas contêm 7 respostas diferentes), algumas delas explicou bem o como ocorre o sqlinjection? Claro que se entrou em concordância com os demais participantes dos debates não faz sentido eu perguntar isto, é só acaso tenha restado alguma duvida. [...]

Comment: [...] Por que digo isto? Pelo fato que uma pergunta existente no mesmo sentido pode receber uma recompensa solicitando mais detalhes ou que façam respostas novas, quero dizer, tem muitas saídas de como ajustar ou melhorar perguntas e/ou respostas sobre o assunto no site. A não ser que o assunto seja realmente especifico demais. Realmente nem quero estender o debate e nem causar mal estar a ninguém, só quero ajudar você a ser ajudado e obter resultados produtivos para ti e para a comunidade.

Comment: Só pra constar, eu dei um bônus naquela questão (gastei um pouco da reputação) para trazer a resposta do XKCD oficialmente, sem que para isso precise manter respostas em lugares diferentes. Talvez nessa longa conversa (que começou a perder o sentido). tenha faltado um dado importantíssimo; fechamento por duplicata NÃO é punição. é Indexação. As duplicatas, diferente dos outros fechamentos, não são eliminadas pelo sistema. Elas servem para que pesquisas diferentes apontem para uma reunião de soluções para o problema, e procura se manter o post original e/ou mais completo sempre que possível.

Comment: Não fossem os 4 negativos, eu até discutiria a remoção dela, pois outro problema é que uma vez o conteúdo postado, não pertence mais ao autor e sim à comunidade (tanto que o sistema mesmo já dá um alerta de vandalismo caso hajam remoções seguidas de conteúdo próprio). Entretanto, penso que se ha o senso de colaboração e de comunidade, você mesmo poderia restaurá-la (afinal bastaria um positivo para já reverter os pontos) mantendo o mérito por ter trazido a tirinha, e servindo de índice para que todos achem o post canônico. E, provavelmente, em algum tempo até a negativação seria revertida.

Comment: Prezado @Bacco há um fenômeno no SO, não só no SO em português, de que quando uma questão começa a receber downvotes, por efeito manada muitos outros usuários dão também downvote. Não creio que seria revertido, ainda que como você mesmo citou, eu creio que a questão tinha algum mérito. Minha sugestão: recrie uma pergunta idêntica. Eu de fato não me importo se o mérito de trazer a tirinha ficar para você.

Answer (score 6):

> 1) minha questão foi marcada como duplicada fornecendo outras duas questões que estão ligeiramente fora do escopo da minha e são suficientemente diferentes;

Pode acontecer. Nem todo mundo é perfeito. Se julga o fechamento equivocado, apresente os comentários com seus argumentos, ou melhor, edite sua pergunta e deixe-a mais clara a ponto de ficar nítidas as diferenças e vote para reabrir a pergunta. Ela seguirá o fluxo natural de toda e qualquer pergunta fechada que é entrar na fila de análise e, se outros usuários concordarem com a reabertura o sistema automaticamente reabrirá a pergunta - independente da vontade dos moderadores - sim, nós podemos reverter a decisão de um moderador e essa é uma das belezas da comunidade.

> 2) a questão foi fechada minutos depois de ser feita sem a devida apreciação de muitos usuários, isto é, a opinião de um único moderador valeu mais que a opinião de muitos outros;

Sim, moderador foi eleito para isso e a opinião dele vale mais (para ser eleito moderador passa-se por um processo bastante árduo para garantir que o usuário tenha conhecimento da comunidade) - por sinal eles geralmente evitam fazê-lo para evitar que usuários, como você, interpretem errado a sua atuação. Se discorda, revise a resposta dada no item 1 acima.

> 3) minha questão tem méritos em si e um escopo muito bem definido, tal que impedir a questão de ser respondida e fornecer como alternativa questões que estão ligeiramente fora do escopo, no meu entender, é simplesmente adicionar ruído a informação que se quer registrar aqui no SOpt.

Se tem méritos, logo ela será reaberta.

> Gostaria de salientar que há uma questão como essa, com milhares de votos no stackoverflow em inglês. Ao que tudo indica o mérito da questão em si é importante e só estou utilizando esse fato para dizer que esse conhecimento foi considerado útil e importante por milhares de usuários.

Não. Pode parecer fazer sentido no início, mas com o tempo você verá que não existe uma relação bijetora entre as duas comunidades. Muita coisa que está aberta lá não é bem recebida aqui; assim como tem muitas perguntas que estão abertas aqui seriam prontamente fechadas lá. O fato de existir uma pergunta aberta e bem recebida lá não tem implicação alguma no processo dentro da nossa comunidade.

Mas isso não quer dizer que a pergunta não pode ser reaberta. Como eu já disse, se acha que tem méritos, vote para reabrir e aguarde.

**Pontos que precisam ficar claros após esta discussão:**

1. Fechamento é reversível, se a pergunta foi fechada, ela pode ser reaberta, independente de como ela foi fechada;
2. O fato de um moderador ter fechado uma pergunta não é abuso de poder; a função dele é essa.
3. Acusar qualquer usuário de te negativar como vingança é, sim, uma afronta, independente se o usuário é ou não moderador;
4. Se acha que levou votos negativos por vingança, sinalize aos moderadores - eles (e somente eles) podem ver quem são os autores dos votos e, se for o caso, investigarão se a acusação é válida. Inclusive, se suspeitar que foi um moderador, reporte aos outros e pode ter a certeza que o moderador envolvido não influenciará nesse processo;
5. A comunidade possui um [Código de Conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct), por favor respeitá-lo sempre;
6. O processo de migração de conteúdo em inglês para o nosso já foi discutido anteriormente e foi tratado na página [Posso traduzir perguntas/respostas de outros idiomas para o Português?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)
7. Se quer discutir algo no Meta, seja direto; uma discussão clara e saudável só pode ser construída a partir de uma pergunta/problema clara.

Comment: Só complementando, sobre um ponto que você não mencionou: a pergunta foi fechada "em minutos" porque nós moderadores não temos condições de ficar separando postagem para olhar depois – muito menos ferramentas que ajudem nisso. Se vemos algo e consideramos que devemos atuar, melhor atuarmos sempre na hora. Claro que, como já foi dito, qualquer decisão nossa pode ser discutida e revertida, inclusive pela própria comunidade, sem participação de moderadores, como você falou.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, mas estas são palavras que fariam muito mais sentido vindo de um moderador :D

Comment: O sexto ponto parece o mais importante porque no fundo agora entendi que é disso que se trata, uma pergunta boa que foi feita em 2008 no SOen quando não havia outra, mas aqui em 2019 já existe resposta para isto, simples assim. Discussão de muito trabalho pra pouca coisa.